# Linux Crypto API headers missing

Tags: debian, linux-kernel, header-file

As soon as headers are essential to deal with crypto algorithms, provided by kernel, I've installed `linux-headers-4.4.0-1-amd64`.

However, this did not added files like `crypto.h`, `module.h` and `init.h` to my `/usr/include/linux` directory.

After googling around I've learned, that there were older versions of linux, that used `linux-kernel-headers` package which contains all needed headers. However, when I tried to install it turned out, that `apt` replaced it with `linux-libc-dev` package, which is already installed and does not contain needed headers.

So, the question is what should I install to get certain headers?

My OS is `Debian Stretch`.

Comment: What are you trying to compile? Userland software or kernel modules? If it's userland software then you shouldn't be using these headers, because they define stuff that you can't link against. If it's kernel modules then there's something wrong in your build automation because it should pick the headers where they are.

Comment: @Gilles  just want to access built-in crypto algorithms from userland. I'm using JetBrains Clion. It could possibly be fixed somehow within IDE settings, but not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've already installed the necessary packages (`linux-headers-4.4.0-1-amd64` and its dependency, `linux-headers-4.4.0-1-common`), but the headers don't end up in `/usr/include/linux`, they end up in `/lib/modules/$(uname -r)/source/include/linux`.

As [Gilles](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/885/gilles) points out, these headers are only intended to be used by the kernel; they're exposed via `/lib/modules` so that out-of-tree modules can be easily built. Since you were looking for the header files by name I assumed you were aiming to use the crypto API in a kernel context, but if not you should use a crypto library in userspace.